# Getting geoJson from Google MAP api or Places Api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How do we get the Polygon GeoJSON Data returned by google  as in this image below.

[image: Geographical Boundary of Delhi as Given by Google]

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know why this was down voted. This Question is not trivial .

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the data?

Comment: I have to do a Mongo geoSpatial search based on MultiPolygon to get all the Documents. I have data with point information. I can do a query with Radius , but that will not suffice my requirement.

Comment: I don't think you can pull the data from the map directly. You'd have to find the data for that region direcly and then store it as geospatial information your database can perform operations on.

Comment: Here is the answer to your other question you just deleted: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4155

Comment: It Just says its not Supported. Doesnt say why its not supported or what is the technical Bottle-Neck . Just Curious to know that ...